# QString encoding with special character

Tags: encoding, utf, qstring

I m trying to convert QString with special character to const char but I did not succeed.
my function is:

```
void class::func(const QString& fileName) // fileName = "â.tmp" 
{ 
  qDebug()<< fileName; // display "â.tmp"
  const char* cfileName = fileName.toAscii().data();
  qDebug() << cfileName;  // display "a?.tmp" 
}
```

qDebug()<< fileName display the true value that is "â.tmp" but after converting it to const a char*, I do not succeed to have the right value.

In the second time I try to use

```
const char* cfileName = QString::fromUtf8(fileName.toAscii().data());
```

but I did not still have the right value, it display the same thing: `a?.tmp`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`ASCII` character set does not have the character `â`, so what you are trying to do is impossible.

You could try this:

```
const char* cfileName = = fileName.toUtf8().data();
```